# Python find max of index 1 & 2 in a list of list

Tags: python

In a list

```
[
[[ 979, 2136, 3427, 2221]],

 [[1497,  697, 2843,  721]],

 [[2778, 2194, 3903, 2233]],
]
```

Iterated as such

```
for line in lines:
    for x1, y1, x2, y2 in line:
```

I would like to find the max value of (x1 or x2 whichever is max) and (y1 y2 whichever is max)

Comment: What is the output? Could you properly format your input?

Comment: `max(x1, x2)` and `max(y1, y2)` ?

Comment: Are you looking to find the max per row (small list), or the overall max?

Comment: Are you sure you are working with a list of lists? That looks like the output of a `numpy.ndarray` to me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
[*map(lambda x: list(map(max, [x[0][:2], x[0][2:]])), mylist)]
```

```
[[2136, 3427], [1497, 2843], [2778, 3903]]
```

Comment: I like your answer but looking for the absolute max of all elements, all the x and all the y

Comment: Can you include your expected output? I'm afraid I just don't understand what you want

Comment: To the given example it would be 3903 for x and 2233 for y

Answer (score 0):

```
import sys
max_x, max_y = [-sys.maxsize,-sys.maxsize]
lines = [
          [[979,2136,3427,2221]],
    
          [[1497,697,2843,721]],
            
          [[2778,2194,3903,2233]]
]
for line in lines:
     for x1, y1, x2, y2 in line:
         if max(x1,x2) > max_x:
             max_x = max(x1,x2)
         if max(y1,y2) > max_y:
             max_y = max(y1,y2)
```

If your points have only positive values you can initialize max_x and max_y to 0.

Answer (score 0):

I'd prefer a more verbose (but I'd argue also more readable) version of Nicolas' answer which preserves the `for` loops and uses a named tuple for more meaningful output:

```
from collections import namedtuple

Coordinate = namedtuple('Coordinate', ['x', 'y'])

lines = [[[ 979, 2136, 3427, 2221]], [[1497,  697, 2843,  721]], [[2778, 2194, 3903, 2233]]]

maximums = []

for line in lines:
    for x1, y1, x2, y2 in line:
        maximums.append(Coordinate(x=max(x1, x2), y=max(y1, y2)))

print(maximums)
# prints [Coordinate(x=3427, y=2221), Coordinate(x=2843, y=721), Coordinate(x=3903, y=2233)]
print([Coordinate(x=3427, y=2221), Coordinate(x=2843, y=721), Coordinate(x=3903, y=2233)])
# prints [(3427, 2221), (2843, 721), (3903, 2233)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to find the max of each set:

```
ls1 = [[[ 979, 2136, 3427, 2221]],
       [[1497,  697, 2843,  721]],
       [[2778, 2194, 3903, 2233]]]

ls2 = [[max(a[0][:2]),
        max(a[0][2:])]
       for a in ls1]

print(ls2)
```

Output:

```
[[2136, 3427],
 [1497, 2843],
 [2778, 3903]]
```

---

---

To find the max of *all* the `x`s and `y`s:

```
ls1 = [[[ 979, 2136, 3427, 2221]],
       [[1497,  697, 2843,  721]],
       [[2778, 2194, 3903, 2233]]]

x = max([i for j in [a[0][:2] for a in ls1] for i in j])
y = max([i for j in [a[0][2:] for a in ls1] for i in j])

print(x, y)
```

Output:

```
2778 3903
```